# Cannot encrypt using react-native-rsa-native

Tags: react-native

I'm having a problem on how to encrypt my message. I'm using `react-native-rsa-native`

Here's my error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'encrypt')
```

Here's my code:

```
import { RSA } from 'react-native-rsa-native';

listenerMiddleware.startListening({
  actionCreator: onRegister,
  effect: async (action, listenerApi) => {
    const RSAKey = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
      ${CONFIG.RSA}
      -----END PUBLIC KEY-----`;

    const encryptEmail = await RSA.encrypt(action.payload.email, RSAKey);

      await listenerApi
        .dispatch(
          registrationApi.endpoints.registerUser.initiate({
            email: encryptEmail,
            password: action.payload.password,
            passwordConfirmation: action.payload.passwordConfirmation,
          }),
        )
        .unwrap();
    }
});
```

Note: `action.payload.email` and `RSAKey` have a value. I tried to `console.log` it multiple times